# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. with celery beat

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

I have a periodic task which creates and saves model every second. So i configured this

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'myapp.tasks',
)

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'periodic_task': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.periodic_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
    },
}
```

and typical *celery.py*:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

app = Celery('myapp')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

and finally i've configured **supervisord** to start this:

```
[program:myapp-celery]
command=/home/me/myapp/venv/bin/celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/me/myapp
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/me/myapp/logs/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/me/myapp/logs/celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

stopwaitsecs = 600
stopasgroup=true
priority=1000
```

And it starts function in **tasks.py** which uses imported model, which as i understand is not loaded yet, causing this error

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.>
```

So i want some hook or flag indicating that everything is set so that my schedule can start executing this periodically.

Comment: I'm not using supervisord and updated from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0rc3 today and am now getting the same error.  If this ticket gets more traction, and it would help, I can send more details.

Comment: currently i get around this issue, setting up priority for django to start it before celery worker and beat, but i don't think that's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its related, or not, but a similar problem with celery 4.2.0rc3 was reported here:

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4699

and fixed here:

https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/4719

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command:

celery -A myapp worker -l info

Comment: Actually i'm using this command `command=/home/me/myapp/venv/bin/celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=INFO` but there should be something specifying that everything is set and celery can start executing.